# Problems loading Stata 13 and Rdata files. New issue

Tags: r, stata

This morning I was working with some data, and R froze.  I restarted and was no longer able to load my data.  I am unsure what's going on.  I have spent hours.  I tried Rstudio and it works, sort of.  Not all of my code transfers over to functions in Rstudio.  I would rather get this to work in the regular R console.

I'm running

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

MAC OSX 10.12.5
```

The data can be found here:
http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSDocumentationWV5.jsp

I'm not using the integrated data because I am running two waves separately -  I don't need every wave.

```
setwd('~/Desktop/')
dat1 <- read.dta13('WV5_data_stata_V_2015_04_18.dta')
#File not found.

dat1 <- read.dta13('WV5_data_stata_V_2015_04_18.dta',convert.factors = TRUE, generate.factors = FALSE, encoding = "UTH-8", fromEncoding =NULL, convert.underscore = FALSE, missing.type = FALSE, convert.dates = TRUE, replace.strl = TRUE, add.rownames = FALSE, nonint.factors = FALSE, select.rows = NULL)
#File not found.

dat1 <- read.dta13('~/Desktop/WV5_data_stata_V_2015_04_18.dta')
#File not found.

dat1 <- read.dta13('WV5_data_stata_V_2015_04_18.dta',convert.factors = TRUE, generate.factors = FALSE, encoding = "UTH-8", fromEncoding =NULL, convert.underscore = FALSE, missing.type = FALSE, convert.dates = TRUE, replace.strl = TRUE, add.rownames = FALSE, nonint.factors = FALSE, select.rows = NULL)
#File not found.

dat1 <- read.dta13('~/Desktop/WV5_data_stata_V_2015_04_18.dta',convert.factors = TRUE, generate.factors = FALSE, encoding = "UTH-8", fromEncoding =NULL, convert.underscore = FALSE, missing.type = FALSE, convert.dates = TRUE, replace.strl = TRUE, add.rownames = FALSE, nonint.factors = FALSE, select.rows = NULL)
#File not found.

dat<- load("WV5_Data_R_v_2015_04_18 2.rdata")
class(dat)
#[1] "character"

#Your version of R is up to date
```

Comment: So? what is happening? Errors? Unexpected results? What ....? Oh, now that I edited the code section, the question becomes ... do you know how to use your filesystem tools? I get an error message when attempting to download from that page. Did you succeed? If you think you did, then prove it.

Comment: It said: 'file not found'. I'm fine.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to learn to use your computer. On a Mac I downloaded the "delimited" file (after giving that webpage an obviously bogus email address),  and it was a CSV format:

```
> dat1 <- read.csv('~/Downloads/F00003607-WV5_Data_ascii_delimited_v_2015_04_18/WV5_Data_ascii_v_2015_04_18.dat', header=FALSE)
> str(dat1)
'data.frame':   83975 obs. of  408 variables:
 $ V1  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ V2  : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V3  : int  2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ V4  : int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
 $ V5  : int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
 $ V6  : int  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ V7  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V8  : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V9  : int  1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V10 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V11 : int  2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V12 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V13 : int  3 4 2 2 4 3 3 4 2 3 ...
 $ V14 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V15 : int  2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V16 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V17 : int  4 3 4 3 4 2 2 4 2 3 ...
 $ V18 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V19 : int  2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 ...
 $ V20 : int  3 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ V21 : int  1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ V22 : int  2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ V23 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ V24 : int  2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ V25 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V26 : int  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ V27 : int  2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ V28 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V29 : int  2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V30 : int  2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ V31 : int  8 8 8 9 8 6 8 9 8 8 ...
 $ V32 : int  1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ V33 : int  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ V34 : int  2 0 2 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 ...
 $ V35 : int  0 0 2 2 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ V36 : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V37 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V38 : int  1 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ V39 : int  0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ V40 : int  2 0 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ V41 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ V42 : int  0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ V43 : int  2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ V44 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V45 : int  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V46 : int  2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V47 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V48 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V49 : int  2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ V50 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V51 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V52 : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ V53 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V54 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V55 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V56 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V57 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V58 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V59 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V60 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V61 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V62 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V63 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V64 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V65 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V66 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V67 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V68 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V69 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V70 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V71 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V72 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V73 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V74 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V75 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V76 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V77 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V78 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V79 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V80 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V81 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V82 : int  -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 -4 ...
 $ V83 : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 1 1 3 3 ...
 $ V84 : int  3 3 1 2 3 1 1 2 3 2 ...
 $ V85 : int  2 7 8 6 10 5 9 9 10 10 ...
 $ V86 : int  6 5 6 6 1 7 7 8 9 6 ...
 $ V87 : int  4 4 4 2 2 4 2 3 1 4 ...
 $ V88 : int  1 1 1 1 4 1 4 2 3 3 ...
 $ V89 : int  3 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 1 3 ...
 $ V90 : int  3 1 2 3 1 3 3 1 1 4 ...
 $ V91 : int  4 2 2 4 1 4 1 3 2 4 ...
 $ V92 : int  3 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 1 4 ...
 $ V93 : int  3 3 2 3 4 3 4 4 1 5 ...
 $ V94 : int  6 1 1 2 6 1 1 6 1 4 ...
 $ V95 : int  1 0 4 1 0 2 2 0 1 3 ...
 $ V96 : int  2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ V97 : int  1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ V98 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 1 ...
 $ V99 : int  -1 3 2 2 3 3 2 1 3 3 ...
  [list output truncated]
```

If you feel you really need to use a dta formatted file, then I have had better experience with haven's `read_dta` than foreign's `read.dta`. I do admit that it did seem to take way too long for that file import to succeed, but it did. It's a big file, 408 columns:

```
> dat2 <- read_dta("~/Downloads/F00003601-WV5_Data_stata_dta_v_2015_04_18/WV5_Data_stata_v_2015_04_18.dta")
> names(dat2)
  [1] "V1"            "V1A"           "V1B"           "V2"            "V2A"          
  [6] "V3"            "V4"            "V4_CO"         "V5"            "V5_CO"        
 [11] "V6"            "V6_CO"         "V7"            "V7_CO"         "V8"           
 [16] "V8_CO"         "V9"            "V9_CO"         "V10"           "V11"          
 [21] "V12"           "V13"           "V14"           "V15"           "V16"          
 [26] "V17"           "V18"           "V19"           "V20"           "V21"          
 [31] "V22"           "V23"           "V24"           "V25"           "V26"          
 [36] "V27"           "V28"           "V29"           "V30"           "V31"          
 [41] "V32"           "V33"           "V34"           "V35"           "V36"          
 [46] "V37"           "V38"           "V39"           "V40"           "V41"          
 [51] "V42"           "V43"           "V43_01"        "V43_02"        "V43_03"       
 [56] "V43_04"        "V43_05"        "V43_06"        "V43_07"        "V43_08"       
 [61] "V43_09"        "V43_10"        "V43_11"        "V43_12"        "V43_13"       
 [66] "V43_14"        "V43_15"        "V43_16"        "V43_17"        "V43_18"       
 [71] "V43_19"        "V43_20"        "V43_21"        "V43_22"        "V43_23"       
 [76] "V43_24"        "V43_25"        "V43_26"        "V43_27"        "V43_28"       
 [81] "V43_29"        "V43_30"        "V44"           "V45"           "V46"          
 [86] "V47"           "V48"           "V49"           "V50"           "V51"          
 [91] "V52"           "V53"           "V54"           "V55"           "V56"          
 [96] "V57"           "V58"           "V59"           "V60"           "V61"          
[101] "V62"           "V63"           "V64"           "V65"           "V66"          
[106] "V67"           "V68"           "V69"           "V69_HK"        "V70"          
[111] "V70_HK"        "V71"           "V72"           "V73"           "V73_HK"       
[116] "V74"           "V74_HK"        "V75"           "V76"           "V77"          
[121] "V78"           "V79"           "V80"           "V81"           "V82"          
[126] "V83"           "V84"           "V85"           "V86"           "V87"          
[131] "V88"           "V89"           "V90"           "V91"           "V92"          
[136] "V93"           "V94"           "V95"           "V96"           "V97"          
[141] "V98"           "V99"           "V100"          "V101"          "V102"         
[146] "V103"          "V104"          "V105"          "V106"          "V107"         
[151] "V108"          "V109"          "V110"          "V111"          "V112"         
[156] "V113"          "V114"          "V115"          "V116"          "V117"         
[161] "V118"          "V119"          "V120"          "V121"          "V122"         
[166] "V123"          "V124"          "V125"          "V126"          "V127"         
[171] "V128"          "V129"          "V130"          "V130_CA_1"     "V130_IQ_1"    
[176] "V130_IQ_2"     "V130_IQ_3"     "V130_IQ_4"     "V130_NZ_1"     "V130_NZ_2"    
[181] "V131"          "V132"          "V133"          "V134"          "V135"         
[186] "V136"          "V137"          "V138"          "V139"          "V140"         
[191] "V141"          "V142"          "V143"          "V144"          "V145"         
[196] "V146_00"       "V146_01"       "V146_02"       "V146_03"       "V146_04"      
[201] "V146_05"       "V146_06"       "V146_07"       "V146_08"       "V146_09"      
[206] "V146_10"       "V146_11"       "V146_12"       "V146_13"       "V146_14"      
[211] "V146_15"       "V146_16"       "V146_17"       "V146_18"       "V146_19"      
[216] "V146_20"       "V146_21"       "V146_22"       "V147"          "V148"         
[221] "V149"          "V150"          "V151"          "V151_IQ_A"     "V151_IQ_B"    
[226] "V152"          "V153"          "V154"          "V155"          "V156"         
[231] "V157"          "V158"          "V159"          "V160"          "V161"         
[236] "V162"          "V163"          "V164"          "V165"          "V166"         
[241] "V167"          "V168"          "V169"          "V170"          "V171"         
[246] "V172"          "V173"          "V174"          "V175"          "V176"         
[251] "V177"          "V178"          "V179"          "V180"          "V181"         
[256] "V182"          "V183"          "V184"          "V185"          "V186"         
[261] "V187"          "V188"          "V189"          "V190"          "V191"         
[266] "V192"          "V193"          "V194"          "V195"          "V196"         
[271] "V197"          "V198"          "V199"          "V200"          "V201"         
[276] "V202"          "V203"          "V204"          "V205"          "V206"         
[281] "V207"          "V208"          "V209"          "V210"          "V211"         
[286] "V212"          "V213A"         "V213B"         "V213C"         "V213D"        
[291] "V213E"         "V213F"         "V213G"         "V213H"         "V213K"        
[296] "V213L"         "V213M"         "V213N"         "V214"          "V215"         
[301] "V216"          "V217"          "V218"          "V219"          "V220"         
[306] "V221"          "V222"          "V223"          "V224"          "V225"         
[311] "V226"          "V227"          "V228"          "V229"          "V230"         
[316] "V231"          "V232"          "V233"          "V233A"         "V234"         
[321] "V235"          "V236"          "V237"          "V238"          "V238CS"       
[326] "V239"          "V240"          "V241"          "V242"          "V242A_CO"     
[331] "V243"          "V244"          "V245"          "V246"          "V247"         
[336] "V248"          "V249"          "V250"          "V251"          "V252"         
[341] "V252B"         "V253"          "V253CS"        "V254"          "V255"         
[346] "V255CS"        "V256"          "V257"          "V257B"         "V257C"        
[351] "V258"          "V259"          "V259A"         "V260"          "V261"         
[356] "V262"          "V263"          "V264"          "V265"          "V266"         
[361] "V267"          "Y001"          "Y002"          "Y003"          "sacsecval"    
[366] "secvalwgt"     "resemaval"     "weightb"       "I_AUTHORITY"   "I_NATIONALISM"
[371] "I_DEVOUT"      "defiance"      "WEIGHT1A"      "I_RELIGIMP"    "I_RELIGBEL"   
[376] "I_RELIGPRAC"   "disbelief"     "WEIGHT2A"      "I_NORM1"       "I_NORM2"      
[381] "I_NORM3"       "relativism"    "WEIGHT3A"      "I_TRUSTARMY"   "I_TRUSTPOLICE"
[386] "I_TRUSTCOURTS" "scepticism"    "WEIGHT4A"      "I_INDEP"       "I_IMAGIN"     
[391] "I_NONOBED"     "autonomy"      "WEIGHT1B"      "I_WOMJOB"      "I_WOMPOL"     
[396] "I_WOMEDU"      "equality"      "WEIGHT2B"      "I_HOMOLIB"     "I_ABORTLIB"   
[401] "I_DIVORLIB"    "choice"        "WEIGHT3B"      "I_VOICE1"      "I_VOICE2"     
[406] "I_VOI2_00"     "voice"         "WEIGHT4B"
```

Comment: I've been using this data and other for over 7 years importing it the exact same way, including that morning.  Thanks.

Comment: I found a work around loading the R data.  I was concerned because typical importing of stata data was not working.  I was looking to solve it for the future.